# Go to a directory and then deletes the file

Tags: php

i am having a problem deleting a file in PHP. i have a folder

> "public_html"

which contains all my file

and there is another directory called

> "user_images"

my problem is I can't use unlink() function because i am in public_html directory. I need to go to the user_images folder to delete the file. is there any solution to this? thanks for answering. i am thinking chdir() but i dont know how to use it.

here's what I think:

```
chdir("user_images");
if(chdir("user_images")){
   unlink($file_name);
}
```

Comment: Why not delete the file directly? `unlink('user_images/' . $file_name)`

Comment: wat abt folder permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the file directly by giving filename with it's path

```
$file = 'user_images/' . $file_name;
if(file_exists($file)){
 unlink($file);
}
```